# Xcode find/search text in output log

Tags: xcode, search, logging, filter, nslog

I'm working with massive logs when my app is running, and i was just wondering if there was a way to search for specific text in the output log (where your NSLogs and such appears).

I have about 1000 lines and even when i know the whereabouts of the line i'm looking for, it would be ten times easier if I could either filter or search for specific results. Or anything similar really.

Is there any way to do that? I've looked around but couldn't find anything useful :(

Thanks !

Comment: Can you write output into the log, these were created by yourself?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you're asking.

Comment: To make it simple, i'm working on a big project that has a lot of NSLogs in it, and i would like a simple way to browse through them (in the output view, not the code itself) instead of just scrolling up and down for a long time

Comment: As an example output in your log: `--- myLog: {put here myData} ---`. So you can find you preferred information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

message to the unborn:

you can switch to the Report Navigator: View > Navigators > Show Report Navigator. Or like this:

[image]

then click the topmost Debug icon (most recent one), then Ctrl+F / CMD+F to search the logs

Comment: Thx :) i also learned recently that you can print when in a breakpoint :x what do you mean by "message to the unborn" :P

Comment: There is no this icon. My xcode version is 13.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Simply click where you see the log output and search as you would in the editor (Command-F, enter search text).  Also, highlight and select some text, then Command-E and Command-G work, too.